# CSS Resource not found when opening scene from other JavaFX

Tags: java, css, controller, javafx-2, fxml

I have `ViewMiscFXML.fxml` class in which I have `TreeTableView`, I want styling for that.

But the output says: `WARNING: Resource "../css/styles.css" not found.`

I am opening `ViewMiscFXML.fxml` class from `ViewEmployeeFXML.fxml`

The code for opening this scene is:

```
Stage stage = new Stage();
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
Pane root = loader.load(getClass().getResource("/views/ViewMiscFXML.fxml").openStream());
ViewMiscFXMLController cont = (ViewMiscFXMLController) loader.getController();
// cont.getDetails(fine_name, int_course_name, ext_course_name);
Scene scene = new Scene(root);
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.show();
```

In the above code I opened the class `ViewMiscFXML.fxml`.

Now the problem is that if I open this class from the controller of other class than the css doesn't work, but if I directly open this class from my main class than css works perfect.